# Можно ли в DNS сделать разные порты? И как?

Tags: dns

Можно ли сделать так, чтоб
при переходе на 
**c1.example.com**
открывался **127.0.0.1:80**, а при переходе на **c2.example.com** открывался **127.0.0.1:81**
?

***Если можно, то как?***

Comment: Нельзя, без явного указания порта в адресе всегда будет использоваться порт 80 (http) или 443 (https)

Comment: Спасибо, жаль что нельзя. Я хотел сделать несколько сайтов на одном сервере

Comment: Вы без проблем можете сделать несколько сайтов на одном сервере с помощью nginx или apache2

Comment: Хорошо, поищу информацию

Comment: А всё, нашол смпособ, но это не точтобы через DNS, а через конфигурацию apache

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем в конец файла /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (некоторые ОС создают для каждого виртуального хоста отдельный конфигурационный файл, тог):

[ссылка на код](https://pastebin.com/hT3wQsGp)

Все настройки не заданные для сайта явным образом в директиве VirtualHost, наследуются от глобальных настроек Apache, указанных выше в этом же файле.
Перезапускаем Apache:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Теперь, обращаясь по DNS именам, мы будем получать разные сайты. Если обратиться по IP адресу, то получим сайт teo.mynetwork.ru, т.к. он подключен первым.